# Prove that composing a measurable function with a continuous function results in a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, solution-verification, measurable-functions

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable subset of $\Bbb R^n$, and let $W$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R^m$. If $f:\Omega\to W$ is measurable, and $g:W\to\Bbb R^p$ is continuous, then $g\circ f:\Omega\to\Bbb R^p$ is measurable.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $V\subseteq\Bbb R^p$ be an open set. Then we have that $g^{-1}(V)$ is open. Since $f$ is measurable, $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V))$ is also measurable.

In other words, for every open set $V\subseteq\Bbb R^p$, the set $(g\circ f)^{-1}(V)$ is measurable, and the result holds.

I am a little bit unsure about the wording of the proof. Could someone please check my arguments?

Comment: You've shown that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(V)$ is in the sigma-algebra on $\Omega$, (say it is $\Sigma$) for all $V$ in some collection $C \subset 2^W$ such that $\sigma(C) = \sigma(\tau_{W})$, ($\tau_W$ is the topology on $W$, i.e. just the subspace topology), this means that $C \subset \{Y \subset W : (g \circ f)^{-1}(Y) \in \Sigma \}$, since the RHS is a sigma algebra, we have shown that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(\sigma(C)) \subset \Sigma$ as desired (so that it is measurable).  What you did was use $C = \tau_{W}$ but we can check measurability with other generating sets too.

Comment: Your proof is clear and correct.